# Why an infinite loop doesn't result in an error in model checking with Promela and Spin?

Tags: model-checking, promela, spin

If I write the following code in Promela and run it in Spin in verifier mode it ends with 0 errors. It does report that `toogle` and `init` had unreached states, but those seem to be only warnings.

```
byte x = 0; byte y = 0;
active proctype toggle() {
    do
    :: x == 1 -> x = 0
    :: x == 0 -> x = 1
    od
}
init {
    (y == 1);
}
```

I was confused by this because I thought this would give me a 'invalid end state' error. If I change the body of the *toogle* proctype with a simple `skip` statement it does error out as I expected.

Why is this? Is there a way to force the simulator to report the infinite loop as an error?

Regarding the 'unreached in proctype' messages, adding an `end` label to the `do` loop doesn't seem to do anything.

I am running spin 6.5.0 and ran the following commands:

```
spin.exe -a test.pml
gcc -o pan pan.c
pan.exe
```

These are the outputs, for reference.

With `do` loop:

```
pan.exe

(Spin Version 6.5.0 -- 1 July 2019)
        + Partial Order Reduction

Full statespace search for:
        never claim             - (none specified)
        assertion violations    +
        acceptance   cycles     - (not selected)
        invalid end states      +

State-vector 20 byte, depth reached 3, errors: 0
        4 states, stored
        1 states, matched
        5 transitions (= stored+matched)
        0 atomic steps
hash conflicts:         0 (resolved)

Stats on memory usage (in Megabytes):
    0.000       equivalent memory usage for states (stored*(State-vector + overhead))
    0.292       actual memory usage for states
   64.000       memory used for hash table (-w24)
    0.343       memory used for DFS stack (-m10000)
   64.539       total actual memory usage


unreached in proctype toggle
        ..\test2.pml:7, state 8, "-end-"
        (1 of 8 states)
unreached in init
        ..\test2.pml:10, state 2, "-end-"
        (1 of 2 states)

pan: elapsed time 0.013 seconds
pan: rate 307.69231 states/second
```

With `skip`:

```
pan.exe
pan:1: invalid end state (at depth 0)
pan: wrote ..\test2.pml.trail

(Spin Version 6.5.0 -- 1 July 2019)
Warning: Search not completed
        + Partial Order Reduction

Full statespace search for:
        never claim             - (none specified)
        assertion violations    +
        acceptance   cycles     - (not selected)
        invalid end states      +

State-vector 20 byte, depth reached 1, errors: 1
        2 states, stored
        0 states, matched
        2 transitions (= stored+matched)
        0 atomic steps
hash conflicts:         0 (resolved)

Stats on memory usage (in Megabytes):
    0.000       equivalent memory usage for states (stored*(State-vector + overhead))
    0.293       actual memory usage for states
   64.000       memory used for hash table (-w24)
    0.343       memory used for DFS stack (-m10000)
   64.539       total actual memory usage



pan: elapsed time 0.015 seconds
pan: rate 133.33333 states/second
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this example

```cpp
byte x = 0; byte y = 0;
active proctype toggle() {
    do
    :: x == 1 -> x = 0
    :: x == 0 -> x = 1
    od
}
init {
    (y == 1);
}
```

the `init` process is blocked forever (because `y == 1` is always `false`), but the `toggle` process can always execute **something**. Therefore, there is **no** *invalid end state error*.

Instead, in this example

```cpp
byte x = 0; byte y = 0;
active proctype toggle() {
    skip;
}
init {
    (y == 1);
}
```

the `init` process is still blocked forever, but the `toggle` process can execute its only instruction `skip;` and then terminate. At this point, none of the remaining processes (i.e. only `init`) has any instruction it can execute, so `Spin` terminates with an *invalid end state* error.

```sh
~$ spin -a -search test.pml
pan:1: invalid end state (at depth 0)
pan: wrote test.pml.trail

(Spin Version 6.5.0 -- 17 July 2019)
...
State-vector 20 byte, depth reached 1, errors: 1
...
```

---

> Is there a way to force the simulator to report the infinite loop as an error?

Yes. There are actually multiple ways.

The simplest approach is to use option `-l` of Spin:

```
~$ spin --help
...
-l: search for non-progress cycles
...
```

With this option, Spin reports any **infinite-loop** which does not contain any state with a [**progress**](http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/progress.html) label.

This is the output on your original problem:

```
~$ spin -search -l test.pml
pan:1: non-progress cycle (at depth 2)
pan: wrote test.pml.trail

(Spin Version 6.5.0 -- 17 July 2019)
...
State-vector 28 byte, depth reached 9, errors: 1
...

~$ spin -t test.pml
spin: couldn't find claim 2 (ignored)
  <<<<<START OF CYCLE>>>>>
spin: trail ends after 10 steps
#processes: 2
        x = 0
        y = 0
 10:    proc  1 (:init::1) test.pml:10 (state 1)
 10:    proc  0 (toggle:1) test.pml:5 (state 4)
2 processes created
```

An alternative approach is to use LTL model checking. For instance, you may state that at some point the number of processes (see **[_nr_pr](http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/_nr_pr.html)**) that are in execution becomes equal to `0` (or more, if you admit *some* infinite loops), or check that a particular process terminates correctly using [remote references](http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/remoterefs.html).

Both cases are contained in the following example:

```cpp
byte x = 0; byte y = 0;
active proctype toggle() {
    do
    :: x == 1 -> x = 0
    :: x == 0 -> x = 1
    od;
end:
}
init {
    (y == 1);
}

// sooner or later, the process toggle
// with _pid == 0 will reach the end
// state
ltl p1 { <> toggle[0]@end };

// sooner or later, the number of processes
// that are currently running becomes 0,
// (hence, there can be no infinite loops)
ltl p2 { <> (_nr_pr == 0) };
```

Both the first

```sh
~$ spin -a -search -ltl p1 test.pml
~$ spin -t test.pml
ltl p1: <> ((toggle[0]@end))
ltl p2: <> ((_nr_pr==0))
  <<<<<START OF CYCLE>>>>>
Never claim moves to line 4 [(!((toggle[0]._p==end)))]
spin: trail ends after 8 steps
#processes: 2
        x = 0
        y = 0
        end = 0
  8:    proc  1 (:init::1) test.pml:10 (state 1)
  8:    proc  0 (toggle:1) test.pml:3 (state 5)
  8:    proc  - (p1:1) _spin_nvr.tmp:3 (state 3)
2 processes created
```

and the second

```sh
~$ spin -a -search -ltl p2 test.pml
~$ spin -t test.pml
ltl p1: <> ((toggle[0]@end))
ltl p2: <> ((_nr_pr==0))
  <<<<<START OF CYCLE>>>>>
Never claim moves to line 11    [(!((_nr_pr==0)))]
spin: trail ends after 8 steps
#processes: 2
        x = 0
        y = 0
        end = 0
  8:    proc  1 (:init::1) test.pml:10 (state 1)
  8:    proc  0 (toggle:1) test.pml:3 (state 5)
  8:    proc  - (p2:1) _spin_nvr.tmp:10 (state 3)
2 processes created
```

LTL properties are found to be false.

---

> Regarding the 'unreached in proctype' messages, adding an end label to the do loop doesn't seem to do anything.

The `end` label(s) are used to **remove** the *"invalid end state"* **error** that would be otherwise be found.

For example, modifying your previous example as follows:

```cpp
byte x = 0; byte y = 0;
active proctype toggle() {
    skip;
}

init {
end:
    (y == 1);
}
```

Makes the error go away:

```sh
~$ spin -a -search test.pml
(Spin Version 6.5.0 -- 17 July 2019)
...
State-vector 20 byte, depth reached 1, errors: 0
...
```

One should only ever use an [**end**](http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/end.html) label when one is willing to **guarantee** that a process being stuck with no executable instruction is not a symptom of an undesired deadlock situation.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It's clear now. My confusion was because I though that any process that hasn't reached it ending curly brace was going to be considered in an invalid end state. I didn't know that if the process was still executing something, even an infinite loop, it is not considered in an invalid end state.

Comment: I was confused because the documentation states: "It is considered an invalid end-state error if a system can terminate in a state where not all active processes are either at the end of their code (i.e., at the closing curly brace of their proctype declarations) or at a local state that is marked with and end-state label." By this description my guess was that the toggle process would be in an invalid end state since it never reaches the closing curly brace or and end label.

Comment: But is makes sense now because the toggle process it not at a state that is marked with and end label, the do loop still continues to run, it never blocks.

Comment: @tgonzaleza Yeah, the catch is that in your original example the system does not really terminate, so the definition does not apply.